# Problem to acces shared folder in Ubuntu 14.04 from Yosemite using IP address

Tags: networking

Each time that I have tried in Yosemite " Concect to Server/ server address (smb:// IP adrress i want to connect) " I got an error "there was a problem connecting to the server using the IP address". Everything is working fine. 
Anyone have an idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: This is a problem with Mac, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with `cifs://` instead of `smb://`

In OS X this will enable the older version of the smb protocol.

Comment: I did and still the same error message ...